# Error while bootsrapping the node on Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef. when I bootstrap a node I get the error cookbook version depends on chef version [">= 14.0"], but the running chef version is 12.21.4. By default the cookbook version is set that's what I came to know but how to know which version of cookbook will work for which chef version. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Look at any cookbook's `metadata.rb`. You may see a line similar to the following, which acts as a `chef-client` version constraint on the cookbook:

```
chef_version '>= 12.1'
```

So if you get an error that the cookbook requires a specific Chef version to run, you will need to install a version of `chef-client` that satisfies the cookbook requirement.

---

If you don't see this line, the cookbook does not enforce a client version requirement but this **does not guarantee** that the cookbook code will work for your version of `chef-client` as resources or newer syntax may be used in the cookbook that your Chef version does not support.